# SQL Adapter does not return result set when select after insert into the table

Tags: sql-server-2008, worklight-adapters

I am using SQL Adapter in IBM Worklight 6.1 and SQL Server 2008
Before insert the data to the table, I check whether the data is exist in the database or not.
If true, I select one column from the existed row.
Otherwise, I insert into the table and select one column of them.

The problem is when I insert and select the column, the adapter return only the insertion result.

```
{
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "updateStatementResult": {
      "updateCount": 1
   }
}
```

After I invoke the same query again, it return the result set.

```
{
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "resultSet": [
      {
         "ACCIDENTID": "A01407V00001"
      }
   ]
}
```

The following is my table schema

```
CREATE TABLE accident 
(
    AccidentID varchar(13) NOT NULL,
    Date varchar(12),
    Time varchar(5),
    Location varchar(150),
    City varchar (20),
    AssClaimNo varchar(17),
    LitClaimNo varchar(17),
    AssID varchar(9),
    LitID varchar(9),
    CLicenPlateNumber varchar(7),
    PRIMARY KEY (AccidentID)
);
```

And this is my SQL statement

```
DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(12) = '15 Jul 2014';
DECLARE @TIME VARCHAR(6) = '11:13';
DECLARE @ASSID VARCHAR(10) = '20140700a';

IF((SELECT COUNT(A1.ACCIDENTID)
    FROM ACCIDENT A1
    WHERE A1.DATE = @DATE AND A1.TIME = @TIME AND A1.ASSID = @ASSID) > 0) 
BEGIN  
    SELECT A.ACCIDENTID  
    FROM ACCIDENT A  
    WHERE A.DATE = @DATE AND A.TIME = @TIME AND A.ASSID = @ASSID  
END;  
ELSE  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ROWS INTEGER;  
    DECLARE @PREFIX VARCHAR(5) = '01407'  

    SET @ROWS = (SELECT COUNT(*)  
    FROM LITIGANT   
    WHERE LITID LIKE 'L'+ RIGHT(CAST(@PREFIX AS VARCHAR(5)),4) +'%')  

    SET @ROWS = @ROWS + 1;   
    DECLARE @LITID VARCHAR(9) = 'L' + RIGHT(CAST(@PREFIX AS VARCHAR(5)),4) + RIGHT('000'+CAST(@ROWS AS VARCHAR(4)),4)
    INSERT INTO LITIGANT (LITID, LNAME, LEMAIL, LTELNUMBER, LDRIVERLICENSE, LCARBRAND, LCARCOLOR, LCARLICENPLATE, LINSNAME, LINSNUMBER)
        VALUES(@LITID, 'Sample', 'sample@sample.com', '0839281938', '93810392', 'Volvo', 'Red', 'AB1234', '', '')  

    SET @ROWS = (SELECT COUNT(*)   
    FROM ACCIDENT  
    WHERE ACCIDENTID LIKE 'A'+@PREFIX+'%')  

    SET @ROWS = @ROWS + 1   
    DECLARE @ACCID VARCHAR(13) = 'A' + @PREFIX + 'V' + RIGHT('0000'+CAST(@ROWS AS VARCHAR(5)),5)  
    DECLARE @ACCCLAIM VARCHAR(16) = @ACCID + '-01'  
    DECLARE @LITCLAIM VARCHAR(16) = @ACCID + '-02'  
    INSERT INTO ACCIDENT (ACCIDENTID, DATE, TIME, LOCATION, CITY, ASSCLAIMNO, LITCLAIMNO, ASSID, LITID, CLICENPLATENUMBER)   
            VALUES( @ACCID, @DATE, @TIME, 'Bangkok', 'Bangkok', @ACCCLAIM, @LITCLAIM, @ASSID, @LITID, 'AR1234')  

    INSERT INTO CLAIM_STATUS  
    (CLAIMID, STATUS, ACCIDENTID)  
    VALUES(@ACCCLAIM, 0, @ACCID)  

    INSERT INTO CLAIM_STATUS  
    (CLAIMID, STATUS, ACCIDENTID)  
    VALUES(@LITCLAIM, 0, @ACCID)  

    SELECT @ACCID AS ACCIDENTID
END;
```

Is there a way to get the resultSet when insert into the table ?

Thank you for all suggestions and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get result set of inserted record by following format:

```
DECLARE @YourTableVariable TABLE(Column1 INT, Column2 INT)

INSERT INTO YourTable( Column1, Column2 )
OUTPUT Inserted.Column1, Inserted.Column2 INTO @YourTableVaribale
VALUES  ( @Column1, @Column2)


Select * From @YourTableVariable
```

Comment: How can I get the result from that table variable? SELECT statement?

Comment: I append this code in the statement in Adapter 
`DECLARE @ACCIDENT_TEMP TABLE(ACCID VARCHAR(16))
INSERT INTO @ACCIDENT_TEMP( ACCID )
OUTPUT Inserted.ACCID INTO @ACCIDENT_TEMP
VALUES  (@ACCID)

SELECT * From @ACCIDENT_TEMP`
It works on SQL Server, but the Adapter still return only updateStatementResult.